# Django-tastypie-mongoengine giving failing on linux

Tags: django, rest, mongoengine, tastypie

Working with django-tastypie-mongoengine

Same configuration works fine on local server/ windows server. On linux server, giving the following error:

`{"error_message": "'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_reset_already_indexed'", "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 217, in wrapper\n    response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 459, in dispatch_list\n    return self.dispatch('list', request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie_mongoengine/resources.py\", line 373, in dispatch\n    return super(MongoEngineResource, self).dispatch(request_type, request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 491, in dispatch\n    response = method(request, **kwargs)\n\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 1299, in get_list\n    objects = self.obj_get_list(bundle=base_bundle, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))\n\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 2112, in obj_get_list\n    objects = self.apply_filters(bundle.request, applicable_filters)\n\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 2084, in apply_filters\n    return self.get_object_list(request).filter(**applicable_filters)\n\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie_mongoengine/resources.py\", line 309, in get_object_list\n    self._reset_collection()\n\n  File \"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tastypie_mongoengine/resources.py\", line 301, in _reset_collection\n    self._meta.queryset._reset_already_indexed()\n\nAttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute '_reset_already_indexed'\n"}`

Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to uninstall mongoengine 0.8.0RCX and install mongoengine 0.7.10

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me as well after upgrading Mongoengine from 0.7.9 to 0.8.4 It turns out, that they fixed this issue with version v0.4.2 of django-tastypie-mongoengine.

In your virtualenv (if you use one):

`$ pip install django-tastypie-mongoengine==0.4.2`

or if you want the latest version:

`$ pip install django-tastypie-mongoengine -U`

And you're golden :-)

> Build info here: [Build for django-tastypie-mongoengine](https://readthedocs.org/builds/django-tastypie-mongoengine/600407/)
>
> HEAD is now at 703fa87 For newer versions of MongoEngine `_reset_already_indexed` is not needed anymore.